# Algorithm for multivariate polynomial system

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, systems-of-equations

Is there any algorithm that can solve multivariate polynomial systems ? I remember some stuff about Groebner basis and elimination theory but I don't remember of any Algorithm that take as input a system and give as an output the solution of the system. I would like to implement such an algorithm on magma or sage.

Comment: You might look to see whether those computer algebra programs already have built-in commands for solving multivariate polynomial systems.

Comment: Well, I didn't find such a command. Maybe I didn't look at the right places but for the moment I didn't find it.

Comment: Anything useful at https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0398 ? Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417109/using-magma-to-solve-a-multivariate-polynomial-system-with-parameters

Comment: Yeah that's the kind of stuff I should look for but I was wondering if there is a general method to do it. Because doing the elimination method lie on our observation.

Comment: I don't know what "lie on our observation" means.

Comment: I mean for exemple if you look at the elimination Ideal you can find some conditions on the zero of the system